# Mac cannot browse, ping works fine

Tags: macos, networking, mac, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I cannot browse websites in Chrome/Safari. Internet works, ping works, traceroute works.

Even "`telnet google.com 80`" works!! (shows me html-code).

But not in browsers. Tried Safari, Chrome - timeout.

Tried this, didn't help:

- killing "mDNSResponder"
- rebooting
- restarting router
- resetting pram

Nothing helps.

MacBook Air, **no antiviruses, firewall disabled**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, this helped:

- Removing ALL wi-fi networks from "System preferences - Networking - Advanced"
- Restarting the router again (weird since all other devices, smartphones and my windows laptop were working fine)

Comment: Wow, is this some secret code or what?! Little Snitch and Radio Silence trials messed up my internet connectivity. Can ping but not browse. This trick works, so far.

Answer (score 8):

While an old question, it still appears at the top on Google, so it makes sense to add a new answer.

I found a helpful hint at [this Apple discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2371266).
In short, a rogue process could be holding a crazy number of TCP connections. In my case it was Kaspersky that was failing to connect to the update server but seemingly never releasing connections.

To check for this, run:

```
sudo lsof -n -i TCP
```

If there's a huge number of open connections (in the hundreds) this might be your issue. Try killing the process that is holding them and see if it helps. After killing Kaspersky (and, probably needlessly, restating WiFi) it all went back to normal for me.

How this affects some sites but not others is beyond me.

Comment: Thanks, my anti-virus, Sophos, had a few hundred TCP connections in CLOSE_WAIT state .  I ran `sudo kill -9` on the Sophos PID and connectivity was restored.  I didn’t reset my router.

Comment: Same here, Sophos consumed all filedescriptors,for me it worked again when i disable the "web protection"

Answer (score 3):

Lifting this answer verbatim from another SE site:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/208796/163653

> - Go to System Preferences,choose network
> - Click "advanced", go to the "Hardware" tab, and click on "configure", choose "manually"
> - Click on mtu, change it to "custom" and set the mtu number to 1453 (I dont why but the number is something like a networking secret from ancient times)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I installed flash player virus and it did lot of changes on my system, I think one of them was adding a proxy.

This discussion helped to me to fix it.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8363208

In short, Go to Settings->Network->Wifi->Advanced..-> Proxies

Uncheck all and we can keep Use Passive FTP Mode checked.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen these symptoms when for some reason the wireless network i joined did not have a DNS server configured on the network.

By manually adding a DNS server, such as Google's public DNS (8.8.8.8), to my connection I am able to access all websites just fine.

Answer (score 0):

My customer's MacBook Pro 6,1 got this symptom when it was updated to Sierra 10.12.4. After trying steps above and on other forums, and failing to fix after a 3-1/2 hour reinstall ('remaining' timer counted down from 5 minutes!) there was still connectivity with pings but no traffic getting through to Firefox, Safari, Mail or system connections (no App Store or updates).

The discussion of Extensions led me to the **System>Library>Extensions folder** where I found a 2010 copy of the **AppleAirPort2.kext** file. All I had to do to regain full connectivity was *delete this file* (backed it up of course) and reboot the machine! NOTHING ELSE WORKED. *This fix worked first time.* HOPE THIS HELPS SOMEONE...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I could ping but my browser was not responding. I solved this by going into my network preferences > advanced > and adding 8.8.8.8 to my DNS server